# find the angle of rotation using hough transform

Tags: image, image-rotation, hough-transform, canny-operator

I am trying to find the angle of rotation of an image using Hough transform .
first, I detect the edges using canny edge detector ,then I apply Hough transform.
After that for each theta I sum over the length of lines over that theta and find the histogram for theta.then I 'circshift' that and find a match. for example if I need to shift that for 5 times, the original and rotated image differ by 5 degree. 
the problem is that this method doesn't differ between 180 and 0 for example. however it is logical because hough gives theta only between -90 and 90.
now how can I recognize that the angle of rotation was 0 or 180?

Answer (score 0):

The hough line transform uses a parametrical representation (radius, angle) where:

[image]

[image]

Notice the **open** interval: there is no 180º (*pi* rad) in theta. It is always 0 :)

(same with any possible shifting of the interval,as:

[image]

still, an open interval in 90º (pi/2) )

**EDIT**: Ok, I think I know where the confusion might be. Theta can be between [0,2pi) **only if** you consider **r** to be a positive real number (this is, r>=0). I think this is not your case, since you have said that

> hough gives theta only between -90 and 90

Comment: yes I know that but how we can map this to rotations in interval [-180,180) ? for example how you differ between a rotation of 0 and 180 degree in the first representation that you mentioned? hough will say that both have 0 rotation which is false.How can I understand which rotation has happened?

Comment: In this hough space, the angle is 0º <= theta < 180º (in degrees), i.e. there is no 180º (it is the same as 0). In the Hough space there is no difference between 180º and 0º if you consider "r" to be **real**.